# Table size, adjust to the page

Tags: tables, size, fit

I have a huge table, and I want the table to fit all the entire page in the horizontal direction. However, the table doesn't fit the page, and the columns were cut.
I'm looking for a way to reduce the size and adjust the page.
The output for my table is the one from the image as you can see it only show 4 columns, and they are cut.

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htpb]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\pagewidth}
\begin{tabular}{*{13}{|c}|}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Never use `\adjustbox` with tables: it leads to inconsistent font sizes. This being said, please post a small compilable example code illustrating your problems.

Comment: Seriously, the best solution is:  Don't make big tables! (Others solutions in  [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options)).

Comment: Please make your code compilable. Currently there is not much to say other than what Fran already stated. If you have to present that much information in the form of a single table, start with allowing linebreaks inside of the columns. You will also have to use longtable instead of tabular in order to allow your table to occupy more than one page since your table definitely I too large to fit onto a single page provided you want its contents to be still readable.